# function executes before and result doesnt applies

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im doing better with my project but im still trying to figure out about some things that are not working properly.
For example, i created a button "UTG1" which filters in green a specific range from the matrix. When this button is clicked, only the values that doesnt has GREEN background should be deleted but it happens that all the values are deleted first and then the background is set.
Any clue about this?
Thanks in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="language" content="english">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title>Table Highlighting</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 
$(function(){   
 
 var color = '#33FF36';
 

$('#button').click(function (){
    color='#33FF36';
});
 
$('#button2').click(function (){
    color='#F0FF00';
});
 
 
 $('#button3').click(function (){
  
     $('#tabla td').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'transparent');    
});
});
 
  
$('#button4').click(function (){
    color='#F0FF00';
});
 
 
  $('td').toggle( function() {
    $(this).css('background', color);
  },function(){
  $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
  });
} );
 
 
 
</script>
<style>
table
{
 width: 520px;
 height: 520px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table_botones
{
 width: 520px;
 height: 50px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
td
{
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 1px solid #666666;
 cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
 

 
</head>
<body>
<table id="tabla" width="520" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">AA</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AKs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AQs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AJs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">TAs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A9s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A8s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A7s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A6s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A5s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A4s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A3s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A2s</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AKo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">KK</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">
  KQs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">KJs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">KTs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K9s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K8s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K7s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K6s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K5s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K4s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K3s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K2s</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AQo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">KQo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">QQ</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">QJs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">QTs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q9s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q8s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q7s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q6s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q5s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q4s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q3s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q2s</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AJo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">KJo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">QJo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">JJ</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">JTs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J9s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J8s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J7s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J6s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J5s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J4s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J3s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J2s</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">ATo</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">KTo</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">QTo</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">JTo</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">TT</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T9s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T8s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T7s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T6s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T5s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T4s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T3s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T2s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A9o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K9o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q9o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J9o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T9o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">99</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">98s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">97s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">96s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">95s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">94s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">93s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">92s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A8o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K8o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q8o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J8o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T8o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">98o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">88</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">87s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">86s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">85s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">84s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">83s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">82s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A7o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K7o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q7o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J7o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T7o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">97o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">87o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">77</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">76s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">75s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">74s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">73s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">72s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A6o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K6o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q6o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J6o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T6o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">96o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">86o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">76o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">66</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">65s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">64s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">63s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">62s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A5o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K5o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q5o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J5o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T5o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">95o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">85o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">75o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">65o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">55</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">54s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">53s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">52s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A4o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K4o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q4o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J4o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T4o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">94o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">84o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">74o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">64o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">54o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">44</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">43s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">42s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A3o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K3o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q3o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J3o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T3o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">93o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">83o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">73o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">63o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">53o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">43o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">33</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">32s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A2o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K2o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q2o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J2o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T2o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">92o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">82o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">72o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">62o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">52o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">42o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">32o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="button" >Raise</button>
 <button id="button2" >Call</button>
 
 <button id="ep1" onclick="ep1()">UTG1</button>
 

 
 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 
 function ep1()
 
 {
 
 $('#tabla td').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'transparent');    
}); 
  
 tabla.rows[0].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";  
 tabla.rows[0].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[5].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[10].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[11].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[3].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36"; 
 
  ep2();
  
 }
 
 
function ep2(){
 
   for (var i = 0 ; i < 13; i++) {
 
            for (var j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
    
    if(tabla.rows[i].cells[j].style.backgroundColor!='#33FF36')
             
     {tabla.rows[i].cells[j].innerText='';}
            } 
        }
 }
  
 
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything correctly but the

```
tabla.rows[i].cells[j].style.backgroundColor
```

returns a rgb value where as you are checking HEXACODE so all you need to do is compare with rgb value as mentioned below.

```
if(tabla.rows[i].cells[j].style.backgroundColor!='rgb(51, 255, 54)'){
 {tabla.rows[i].cells[j].innerText='';}
}
```

```js
function ep1()
 
 {
 
 $('#tabla td').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'transparent'); 
}); 
  
 tabla.rows[0].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";  
 tabla.rows[0].cells[4].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[5].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[10].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[0].cells[11].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[1].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[2].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[2].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36";
 tabla.rows[3].cells[3].style.backgroundColor = "#33FF36"; 
 
  ep2();

 }
 
 
function ep2(){
 
   for (var i = 0 ; i < 13; i++) {
 
            for (var j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
    
    if(tabla.rows[i].cells[j].style.backgroundColor!='rgb(51, 255, 54)')
      
     {tabla.rows[i].cells[j].innerText='';}
            } 
        }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="language" content="english">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title>Table Highlighting</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 
$(function(){   
 
 var color = '#33FF36';
 

$('#button').click(function (){
    color='#33FF36';
});
 
$('#button2').click(function (){
    color='#F0FF00';
});
 
 
 $('#button3').click(function (){
  
     $('#tabla td').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'transparent');    
});
});
 
  
$('#button4').click(function (){
    color='#F0FF00';
});
 
 
  $('td').toggle( function() {
    $(this).css('background', color);
  },function(){
  $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
  });
} );
 
 
 
</script>
<style>
table
{
 width: 520px;
 height: 520px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
table_botones
{
 width: 520px;
 height: 50px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
td
{
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 1px solid #666666;
 cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
 

 
</head>
<body>
<table id="tabla" width="520" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">AA</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AKs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AQs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AJs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">TAs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A9s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A8s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A7s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A6s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A5s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A4s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A3s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A2s</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AKo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">KK</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">
  KQs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">KJs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">KTs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K9s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K8s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K7s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K6s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K5s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K4s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K3s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K2s</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AQo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">KQo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">QQ</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">QJs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">QTs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q9s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q8s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q7s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q6s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q5s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q4s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q3s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q2s</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">AJo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">KJo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">QJo</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">JJ</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">JTs</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J9s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J8s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J7s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J6s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J5s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J4s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J3s</td>
  <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J2s</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">ATo</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">KTo</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">QTo</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">JTo</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">TT</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T9s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T8s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T7s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T6s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T5s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T4s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T3s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T2s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A9o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K9o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q9o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J9o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T9o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">99</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">98s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">97s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">96s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">95s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">94s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">93s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">92s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A8o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K8o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q8o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J8o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T8o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">98o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">88</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">87s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">86s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">85s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">84s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">83s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">82s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A7o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K7o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q7o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J7o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T7o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">97o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">87o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">77</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">76s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">75s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">74s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">73s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">72s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A6o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K6o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q6o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J6o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T6o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">96o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">86o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">76o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">66</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">65s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">64s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">63s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">62s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A5o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K5o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q5o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J5o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T5o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">95o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">85o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">75o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">65o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">55</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">54s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">53s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">52s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A4o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K4o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q4o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J4o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T4o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">94o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">84o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">74o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">64o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">54o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">44</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">43s</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">42s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A3o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K3o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q3o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J3o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T3o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">93o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">83o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">73o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">63o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">53o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">43o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">33</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">32s</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">A2o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">K2o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">Q2o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">J2o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">T2o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">92o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">82o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">72o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">62o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">52o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">42o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center">32o</td>
   <td width="40" height="40" align="center" bgcolor="#2692F7">22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="button" >Raise</button>
 <button id="button2" >Call</button>
 
 <button id="ep1" onclick="ep1()">UTG1</button>
 

 
 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jayababu! I appreciate a lot your help!

Comment: Now, i have another doubt, why it doesnt works if i use this one: 

    if(tabla.rows[i].cells[j].style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 255, 255)')

Because i add a different color for other cells, so i want to take out all the cells which are not any of this 2 colors.

Comment: Solved it! i was using 'white' before instead of RGB 255,255,255

Comment: @Luciano Mark it as answer if you found its correct